# Grails app fails to run

Tags: grails, run-app

So, I've just created a brand new grails app, created one Domain with a few fields, and then a controller and a set of views based from the domain (using grails built in generate commands).

I then attempt to run this and get the following error, any clues?: -

```
| Error 2013-10-24 12:08:11,643 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field test.PC.MyName to java.lang.Class
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field test.PC.MyName to java.lang.Class
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field test.PC.MyName to java.lang.Class
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field test.PC.MyName to java.lang.Class
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field test.PC.MyName to java.lang.Class
->>    6 | doCall    in test.PC$__clinit__closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
```

At the risk over overfilling this with data, a quick google suggests this could be something to do with my datasource?  If so my datasource file looks like so which is the standard template for when a project is first generated so should work..? : -

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It also mentions failures with the bootstrap, again I've included it here but its the standard file created on setup and unmodified...?

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Domain code is: -

```
package test

class PC {

    static constraints = {
        MyName()
        MyVal1()
        MyVal2() 
    }
    String MyName
    String MyVal1
    String MyVal2
}
```

Comment: What is your Grails version and your JDK version?

Comment: JDK is 1.7.0 and I'm using GGTS version 3.2.0, it loads up fine before I generate a domain, although there's not a lot there at that stage, but once the domain is created it bombs...  Have added the domain code above just in case this helps...

Comment: How are you using your `test.PC.MyName` variable? Seems you are assigning a Class object into that string variable.

Comment: I haven't done anything with it to the best of my knowledge.  I've literally used the built in functionality of GGTS to create a Grails project, generated a domain within it (see above for content of the domain, hardly anything in there) then used the built in functionality to again generate a controller and views before trying to run it :S

Comment: Change your variable names to start with `lowercase` and regenerate your controllers and views.

Comment: That's done the trick, ridiculous that something so small would cause such a headache yet not get pointed out!  Many thanks Alidad for point that out, if you make that an answer I will gladly mark it as such! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39926/discussion-between-morkpork-and-alidad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java and Groovy naming convention is to start `class` names `uppercase` and variables and `instances` `lowercase`. To take advantage of Grails convention, it is recommended to follow the same convention as java and groovy.  Grails does some magics based on the variable names, for example, Grails matches domain fields to their database fields by their name or Grails bean autowiring is based on bean's name, therefore, creating variables with UpperCase might have confused it in your case.

Comment: cheers!  Got it in one!  You'd think as GGTS can already checks a load of syntax and other stuff a simple check could be put in to check these things as well (in fact it does when generating the classes it tells you to use uppercase, its just variables and instances where no check occurs, very frustrating!)